# How to create a list of notifications in Unity with JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a list of notifications in Unity, which are delivered by a JSON API. The idea is to make a list of news, announcements, etc., where it shows the title and content of the advertisement. In this case it would be "titulo" and "texto".
The url is "(web service name)/API/testnot.php"

This is what JSON gives me:

> [{"_id":{"$oid":"5d30eccda6e0712cfd0832c3"},"titulo":"Primera Notificacion","texto":"Prueba de notificacion"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5d336c36a6e07114ac728cc2"},"titulo":"Segunda notificacion","texto":"Prueba de notificacion 2"}]

Answer (score 1):

Make a class to which the json should be deserialized:

```
[Serializable]
public class Notification
{
    public Id _id;
    public string titulo;
    public string texto;

    [Serializable]
    private class Id
    {
        public string $oid;
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
Notification notification = JsonUtility.FromJson<Notification>(json);
```

If it comes as an array:

```
Notification[] notifications = JsonUtility.FromJson<Notification[]>(json);
```

Although the _id and $oid could be problematic because of the _ and $ I think.

Edit: For the actual request to get the json, just do it similar to the following manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html